# Drop-shadow with rounded corners in vb6

Tags: vb6

Various code is available online which make it possible to have drop-shadow in vb6.

- Some of the use a separate form which has a darkened framework picture of your main form.
- Some others make use of things in-built in windows.

I am planning to make use of the second type since there a numerous forms in my application.
But the 2nd type doesn't allow rounded corners.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: What are you asking for? Just code to draw drop shadows of controls? Of the main window? of custom graphics?